# CustomVertAxis накладывается на Right Axis

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-berlin, teechart

Есть чарт с 4 осями - справа, слева, снизу и ещё одна кастомная справа. В Дельфи 7 всё нормально, а в Берлине она наезжает на правую "обычную" ось.

[image: Пример]

Пробовал подвигать с помощью PositionPercent, но он только внутри графика двигает, а эта ось должна внешней быть, "самой правой". Расширение самого чарта тоже ничего не даёт. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавил CustomAxis, связал её со второй серией.

Установил Chart-Panel-Margins-Right в 16%  (в редакторе)

Установил Axis-Сustom 0-Position в 125%

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]