Как позиционировать легенду под осями в Teechart-е в Delphi
Нужно сдвинуть легенду графика влево до упора, заняв весь низ, включая угол с ???(на схеме). Пробовал  задавать Legend.Left при создании, но толку никакого, в какой-то момент, при Repaint-е и кажется Resize туда ставятся другие значения. Также меняются Top, Allignment и некоторые другие свойства.
Если же я вручную в отладке ставлю Left := 0, то легенда смещается как надо, да, но при этом область с графиком и осями разворачивается на всю область TeeChart-а, накладываясь на легенду.


Установите нужное положение легенды - я сделал Position-Custom - 0% 90%, и измените нижний Margin у Panel (я поставил 12)




К стыду своему, не понял о чём вы.  У легенды нет Position, только Left  и Top.  Есть LeftPersent, наверное это оно, но ставка его в ноль тоже не помогает. Панели, насколько я нашёл, нет ни у чарта, ни у легенды

Добавил картинки. TeeChart Pro

Вот здесь же вы, видимо, нашли Panel: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/955451/291659

Да, это всё есть и в дизайне можно ставить без проблем. Но если график создавался динамически, то уже никаких Position и Panel.
